# Laravel Search Delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I make search and I get the search results, I try to delete a record , its deleted show the message that successfully deleted but after I get the error  throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $id = Hashids::decode($id);
    $id = implode(',', $id);

    $sub = Subs::find($id);
    $sub->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => "Subscription Plan Deleted successfully.",
        'tr'      => 'tr_' . $id,
    ]);
}
```

The routes:

```
Route::post('/subscriptions/search/results','SubsController@searchSubs'); 
Route::get('/subscriptions/restore/{id}', 'SubsController@restore');
```

The link:

```
<a href="{{action('SubsController@destroy', Hashids::encode($sub['id']))}}" class="btn btn-danger btn"
   data-tr="tr_{{$sub['id']}}" data-toggle="confirmation" data-btn-ok-label="Delete" data-btn-ok-icon="fa fa-remove"
   data-btn-ok-class="btn btn btn-danger" data-btn-cancel-label="Cancel"
   data-btn-cancel-icon="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" data-btn-cancel-class="btn btn btn-default"
   data-title="Are you sure you want to delete ?" data-placement="left" data-singleton="true">Delete </a>
```

Comment: add the route and the code, where you make this call

Comment: Check your header what is the type of method called there

Comment: `Route::post('/subscriptions/search/results','SubsController@searchSubs');
Route::get('/subscriptions/restore/{id}', 'SubsController@restore');`

Comment: `a href="{{action('SubsController@destroy', Hashids::encode($sub['id']))}}" class="btn btn-danger btn"
  data-tr="tr_{{$sub['id']}}"
  data-toggle="confirmation"
  data-btn-ok-label="Delete" data-btn-ok-icon="fa fa-remove"
  data-btn-ok-class="btn btn btn-danger"
   data-btn-cancel-label="Cancel"
   data-btn-cancel-icon="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"
    data-btn-cancel-class="btn btn btn-default"
    data-title="Are you sure you want to delete ?"
     data-placement="left" data-singleton="true">
      Delete
                                  </a>`

Comment: You don't appear to have a route set up that points to `SubsController@destroy`.

Comment: I have it Route::resource('subscriptions','SubsController');

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('subscriptions','SubsController');
```

creates a destroy method which requires request type DELETE. 
e.g.
Route::delete(subscriptions/destroy','SubsController@destroy');

to do so you will have to make a form and send a DELETE request like below.

```
<form action="{{ route('routename',$parameter) }}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    <button type="submit" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-danger m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

check your route in console by

```
php artisan route:list
```

**If you cant do that then:**
 remove destroy method from resource like this:

```
Route::resource('subscriptions','SubsController')->except('destroy');
```

Now it will not include destroy method. Now you can make your own route of **get** request and send id of record to delete it

Comment: I try it but when I use my search form to find the subscription plan and I delete a record I get throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);

Comment: Okay. Edit your question and add routes, then controller and then blade file. This exception occurs when your route and request type is mis-matching. e.g. route is post type and your are sending a get request.